# Resume upload in Doc file and have to read the name and other details and then bind in textboxs using asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my project I have a registration form  in which I need to upload user resume. from that resume I need to get the user name and qualification and bind to text box.
I am using asp.net with c#. i have wrote code for upload files and insert into database now the issue is with the reading of the doc file and extract the contents. 
please help me with this & thanks in advance.

Comment: that is a big task because you have to know the extension of the file and than try to read the file and try to figure out where the name and family name for example are located

Comment: I have done reading the extension of files. but the issue is how to locate the contents in doc file.

Comment: what are the valid extention files ?

Comment: case ".doc":
                    contenttype = "application/vnd.ms-word";
                    break;
                case ".docx":
                    contenttype = "application/vnd.ms-word";
                    break;
                case ".xls":
                    contenttype = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
                    break;
                case ".xlsx":
                    contenttype = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
                    break;

Comment: xls and xlsx files are excel file don't u think it's weird to upload a cv in this type of files ?

Comment: see I have check that if user checks Resume check box it will check the uploaded file is doc type else it will go for error mgs .. so don't worry about it my project will accept all kind of extension files and I success in uploading all type of files but the issue regarding only the reading and locate the contents in word document.

Answer (score 1):

If the file is .doc or .docx, you can do almost anything to it with Microsoft Interop Library. Include interop library in your project (I am using VB.Net here)

```
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word

    Dim oWord As Word.Application
    Dim oDoc As Word.Document

    oWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    oWord.Visible = False
    oDoc = oWord.Documents.Open(FullPathofFile)
```

Now you can use oDoc to access different parts of the document; Like Header, Footer, Range etc. Read the contents and retrieve it for your purpose. You may need to develop a logic to find where will be the name and other details to be found.

Comment: I am just trying your code but what is exact meaning for the createobject("word.application) in your code.

Comment: Creates and returns a reference to a COM object. Check out the following link for more details http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7t9k08y5(v=vs.90).aspx